# Javascript/Jquery Help - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

A snippet of my JS below -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.wiseguys();

});

// plugin structure used so we can use the "$" sign safely

(function($) {

// class constructor / "init" function
$.wiseguys = function() {

}
})(jQuery);
```

There is some code I have taken out and obviously code under the $.wiseguys function - but when run in Wordpress, it returns a Type Error - Undefined is not a function. I have not idea why - any thoughts?

It works perfectly fine in static HTML, just not when integrated into Wordpress

Comment: Can you please provide more details for your problem. What do you mean when you say you have taken out?

Comment: You have not included end part of the code ..

Comment: You can't use the `$` safely, based on what you've shown...how does your bottom logic end?

Comment: The JS file is massive - but the problem I am having with stems to calling the wiseguys function - it doesnt trigger anything - and all the scripts are held within this - $.wiseguys = function()

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.wiseguys();
});
```

executes before

```
(function($) {
    // class constructor / "init" function
    $.wiseguys = function() { }
})(jQuery);
```

To be sure it's that case - try changing order of those 2 statements. 
The reason why it happens lies somewhere in the code you've removed. Maybe you've loaded that code dynamically, and the document has already been loaded? This way jQuery(document).ready would execute immediately.

Hope it helps!